# How List<Object> is subtype of List<? super Number>

Tags: java, generics, collections

While reading book ***Java Generics and Collections***. In the section *Wildcards with Super*, I came along one example

```
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dst, List<? extends T> src) {
  for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++) {
     dst.set(i, src.get(i));
  }
}
```

And it's been called like this :

```
Collections.<Number>copy(objs, ints);
```

Above call is valid and its explanation is given as:

> The call is permitted because `objs` has type `List<Object>`, which is a subtype of `List<? super Number>` (since `Object` is a supertype of `Number`, as required by the wildcard) and `ints` has type `List<Integer>`, which is a subtype of `List<? extends Number>` (since `Integer` is a subtype of `Number`, as required by the extends wildcard)

My doubt is ***how `List<Object>` is a subtype of  `List<? super Number>`***?

Comment: @JonSkeet I am not interpreting List<? super Number> correctly, when Object is supertype of all then why List<? super Number> is supertype of List<Object>

Comment: @Prateek: I wouldn't use "subtype" here necessarily, but `Object` certainly satisfies the wildcard in `? super Number` doesn't it?

Comment: @JonSkeet Since Object is supertype of ? super Number. then why List<Object> is subtype of List<? super Number>. yshavit answer is talking about contravariance but i m not getting how compiler understands it.

Comment: @Prateek: Again, I probably wouldn't use subtype and supertype in this context - at least not without double-checking the spec *very* carefully - but I'd say that `Object` satisfies the requirement of the wildcard, and therefore the call is valid. (It may be that it really is technically a subtype; I'd just need to check very carefully.)

Comment: Okay.That means if instead of Object i passed List<Number> then it will also be a valid call as it also satisfies the requirement.Got it.
Thanks...

Comment: @Prateek Think of it this way.  Type `A` is a supertype of type `B` iff every object of type `B` also happens to be of type `A`.  That is the definition of supertype.  So, the question is - is every object of type `List<Object>` also an object of type `List<? super Number>`.  The answer is clearly Yes.

Comment: @DavidWallace Can you put this explaination in your answe too.Might be helpful for others too...

Comment: Yeah, that's not such a bad idea.  Will do.  I might swap it round though, since the question talks about subtypes not supertypes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a definition of subtype.  Type `X` is a *subtype* of type `Y` if and only if every object or primitive of type `X` is also of type `Y`.  So the question you've asked is whether or not (or how) every object of type `List<Object>` is also of type `List<? super Number>`.

Now the part `? super Number` means "any type that is a supertype of `Number`, including `Number` itself".  There are only two such types - `Number` and `Object`.

So `List<? super Number>` is an abstract type that contains `List<Number>` and `List<Object>` and no other types (apart from subtypes of these two, of course).

Comment: but List<Number> cannot be a subtype of list of Number so only left with List<Object> only.

Comment: @Prateek Isn't `Number` a valid substitute for `? super Number` ?

Comment: It is a valid subsitute but i m getting confused with List<Object> arguement,which is been said as subtype of List<? super Number> (where List<Object> can be the valid super and not List<Number>)

Comment: @Prateek `List<Object>` is not technically a subtype of `List<? super Number>`, they're both `List`. `List<Object>` is however a valid substitute for `List<? super Number>` since `Object` is a valid substitute for `? super Number`.

Comment: @zakinster.  No.  `List<Object>` is ABSOLUTELY a subtype of `List<? super Number>`.

Answer (score 1):

`? super` is just Java's weird way of saying "contravariant".

First wrap your head around covariance: `A<? extends B>` is a subtype of `A<? extends C>` iff `B` is a subtype of `C`. So `List<? extends Number>` is a subtype of `List<? extends Object>`.

Contravariance is the opposite: `A<? super B>` is a subtype of `A<? super C>` iff `C` is a subtype of `B`. So `List<? super Object>` is a subtype of `List<? super Number>`.

Comment: Okay, thts what i need...Thanks Chris

Comment: But how this contavariance can be justified,can u explain it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. That's just the definition of a contravariant generic type.

Comment: I mean to say, how compiler understand this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to fight with the description. Think it like this:

`List<? super Number>` means it should be a list that stores any object as long as the object is a super class of Number. So `List<Object>` obviously fits the criteria.

Comment: But in explaination its saying List<Object> is a subtype